# iOS - CGImage cropping rotated rectangle

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, core-image, apple-vision

I am using Vision framework to detect rectangles on images. When Vision detected any rectangle it returns four points of rectangle corners. I would like to crop this rectangle from cgImage but the main problem is how to do it when rectangle is rotated. Because in apple documentation ([CGRect documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect) there is no way to get rectangle by his corners. So how can I crop this rect ?

[image: Example of cgImage with detected rectangle]

I would like to crop only selected rectangle. So I would like to get something like this [image: Expected result of cropping]

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Have a look at CIPerspectiveCorrection CIFilter. This is what you need.

Comment: Yes, this is exacly what i need. Thanks